# Spring security LDAP Authentication without specifying authentication details in the configuration file

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-ldap

We are using Spring security LDAP authentication in our application for authentication purpose. For ldap authentication, we configure a userid and password in the applicationContext-security.xml. I would like to know if there is a way to authenticate via LDAP without specifying the User parameters for accessing the LDAP server in the  configuration(applicationContext-security.xml) file .

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Did you see the answer below? Was it helpful?

Answer (score 1):

[Jasypt](http://www.jasypt.org/encrypting-configuration.html) supports encrypting  `.properties` files and transparently decrypting it when Spring accesses it.

So , you can try to specify the authentication details inside a `.properties`  file , then use Jasypt to encrypt this `.properties`  file . Use `<context:property-placeholder>` to inject the authentication details from the `.properties` files  into the `applicationContext-security.xml`

Comment: Hi Ken, Thanks for the quick response. Actually I do not want to specify the LDAP authentication details anywhere in the configuration files. I want to know if there is a way to provide the ldap authentication without hardcoding the userid & password

Comment: Do you have the same requirement for your other support systems, ala database(s)?  The solution you use there is probably applicable.

Answer (score 0):

If your LDAP allows anonymous access you may not specify `userDn` and `password` in the configuration of `contextSource`. In this case Spring Security will use anonymous for read-write operations.